# dist handling of missing values

Tags: r

I am puzzled by the following behavior of the `dist` function in `R`: According to the documentation `dist` should be able to handle missing values, i.e.

```
y <- matrix(1:9, 3, 3)
y[1, 1] <- NA
y
yd <- dist(y)
```

works just fine and `yd` does not contain any missing values.
So, why does `xd` contain missing values?

```
x <- matrix(rnorm(12000), 2000, 6)

x[1:666, 1:3] <- NA
x[1333:2000, 4:6] <- NA

xd <- dist(x)
```

Comment: Because some pairs of rows have no non-NA values in common?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is important to understand the way it "handles" these missing values. The distances are being computed between rows. So, a natural thing to do is to compute the distance forgetting the columns with missing values.

In your first example every pair of rows has at least two available values in common, while in the second example there are many cases with no such values. On the other hand,

```
x <- matrix(rnorm(12000), 2000, 6)
x[1:666, 1:2] <- NA
x[1333:2000, 4:6] <- NA
anyNA(dist(x))
# [1] FALSE
```

because now at least the third column has no missing values.